# cell_clip and proj_clip parameter in Tensorflow LSTMCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm learning TF to train a language model for my project. I found in [LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) initializer, there are two parameter, cell_clip and proj_clip, that I don't understand. and I don't found any reference about the two parameter online either. Can anyone help me understand those two parameter?

Best

Answer (score 0):

In the official implementation of the rnn_cell, tensorflow defines what proj_clip is :

> proj_clip: (optional) A float value.  If `num_proj > 0` and `proj_clip` is
>         provided, then the projected values are clipped elementwise to within
>         `[-proj_clip, proj_clip]`